# C - Switch-case prints case twice

Tags: c, switch-statement, scanf, getchar

I have written the following switch-case:

```
    char input;
    int run = 1;
    while(run){
        printf("Would you like to update the student's name? Enter Y or N (Y=yes, N=no)\n");
        input = getchar();
        switch (input)
        {
        case 'N':
            run = 0;
            break;
        case 'n':
            run = 0;
            break;
        case 'Y':
            printf("Please enter the updated name\n");
            scanf("%s", st->name);
            run = 0;
            break;
        case 'y':
            printf("Please enter the updated name\n");
            scanf("%s", st->name);
            run = 0;
            break;
        case '\n':
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong input. Please enter a valid input (Y or N)\n");
        }
    }
```

When I run it does this:

```
Please enter the id of the student that you would like to update
1
Would you like to update the student's name? Enter Y or N (Y=yes, N=no)
Would you like to update the student's name? Enter Y or N (Y=yes, N=no)
```

Why does it print the question twice? Can anyone help?
Other than that the cases run as expected.

Comment: You've got the `'\n'` from the 1st question (answer was `"1\n"`). Don't mix `scanf()` and `getchar()`. Always prefer `fgets()` for user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `getchar`  reads all characters including new line characters. Instead use

```
scanf( " %c", &input );
```

Also your switch statement has a duplicated code. Write for example

```
    switch (input)
    {
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
        run = 0;
        break;
    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
        printf("Please enter the updated name\n");
        scanf("%s", st->name);
        run = 0;
        break;
   //...
```

The same approach you can use for other labels of the switch statement. and remove this code

```
    case '\n':
        break;
```